# Where can I find this exact spatula, with a short handle and asymmetric head?

Tags: equipment

What kind of spatula is this? My boyfriend's father has this and I want to get him a new one for Christmas but cannot find it. It does not have a brand on it and he does not know where the spatula came from.

[image: photograph of spatula]

Comment: Are there any markings on it at all?  Also, some measurements might be useful -- it looks to be to be really, really, short handled, but that might be an issue w/ shortening due to the angle the picture was taken at.

Comment: It is a very short handle.  I am not sure on the exact measurements, but it may not even be 12 inches long.

Comment: This looks like an "adaptive utensil" meant for those with arthritis or other difficulties in grasping and fine motor control - the handle is unusually thick and contoured, and the head is much closer in. Amazon has a number of these, notably the OXO Good Grips, but nothing that matches this one exactly. You may want to check out the local pharmacies.

Comment: I have what looks like that exact spatula and I know I got it as a set and I think from Sam's Club.

Comment: Oh my good gouda I have been looking for this EXACT kind of spatula for months now! Did you ever find out where you can get this or even what its proper name is?

Comment: Sarah, do you have any more clues to the infamous spatula?  (eg, do you remember there being any markings on it?  Also, was it completely straight like the rice paddles, or was there a bend between the head & handle?

Comment: I too have been looking. We used to get them at Fred Meyers, but they haven't had them for ten years.

Comment: I broke my tool several months ago and I'm looking for exactly the same one that was pictured above! This is the first time I have ever seen the identical one in my search, Sad, but Glad that I am not alone in my search! Mine came in a Set of 5 utensils as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh0b5.jpg). The only mark on the hand grip is "China" but for some reason I'm thinking this may have been a Costco purchase, just not sure!

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find an exact match but the short, squat shape with a straight top edge suggests that it's for stirring and/or scraping. The flat shape (ie. that although the head is angled at the top, the whole head isn't angled) and thick, inflexible design suggest that it *isn't* supposed to be used for flipping; this would be very difficult as rim of the pan would get in the way -  even if it weren't a problem, you would still have the problem of your knuckles being too close to the pan to avoid burning.

The nearest equivalents I could find are:

**A Saute paddle:**

[image][image]

This is probably the best match. The tool that OP pictures seems good for scraping a pan and will take some force being applied. The angle at the top will also make this easier on the wrist. Slots are also common.

*Or, failing that*

**A Rice spoon/spatula:**

[image]

The overall size and shape are close to a traditional rice spatula/spoon. The angled head is a common design, though less common than round heads. Slots however, are unusual.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like something made for Walmart or target or the like, however that style of spatula looks like a "slotted nylon broad fish turner" google that and variations of that as a search term to find a good match.

I don't know why fish turners aren't more popular in the average home, but they are great tools. Since I don't use Teflon coated pans I prefer stainless, but even so they are great flipping tools.

Comment: I will definitely look on google for that! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good point ... the asymmetric head + short handle would be rather similar to a fish spatula.  (I'm used to them having less coverage (more gaps / large slots) than other styles, so that didn't come to mind right away)

Comment: That's not a fish-slice. The short, squat shape, thick blade and flat angle to the pan (if that makes sense?) would make it very, very difficult to use for that. To me it looks more like a variation on a sushi rice spatula.

Comment: example of rice spatula - https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVj8AOb608uhpxpAVgmjlwE4SgBCz5wjMJRCT-n8-5l-sYaWWr

Comment: @Niall Try digging out rice with that plastic spatula. It ain't gonna work. Honestly the closest traditional tool to this spatula is the fish turner. I looked thoroughly.

Comment: @Escoce Keep in mind that it's for sticky, starchy rice that will come up in clumps, not Uncle Ben's. It's a traditional tool used for this purpose, not something I just made up. Whether or not the tool OP shows is a rice spatula, I don't know, but they're certainly similar.

Comment: Exact shape as the spatula that come with my rice cooker.