# Black silicon spoon slotted paddle

Tags: utensils

I am looking for the pictured kitchen utensil. Black silicone slotted  paddle or spatula.  11 Inches long overall. I have no name on handle other than "CHINA". Tried Google and Amazon.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a nylon spatula from the picture, not silicone, but I can't tell for sure without holding it in my hands. See [How to distinguish between silicone and nylon spatula and judge their quality](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/102688) for hints how to distinguish them.

Comment: See [Where can I find this exact spatula, with a short handle and asymmetric head?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/64055/67)

Comment: @Joe it's literally the same image, looks like an exact duplicate

Comment: @Esther good point.  And I think that it’s been asked other times, too.  (A few people attempted to ask again on that other question)